# Command line 7-Zip exclude

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, zip, 7-zip

I have tried this many times, but not yet got it. How do I use 7-Zip to zip a directory without one directory inside other?

Like:

I have a folder

```
/home/files/
```

and inside that, `directory1/` and `directory2/`.

So how do I 7-Zip files without `directory1/`?

One example of what I had tested:

```
7z a -t7z /home/backups/backup /home/files -x!/directory1
```

I tried adding a flag:

```
-mx0 -x!directory1\
```

But it just says:

> bash: !directory1/: event not found

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I exclude a directory from 7-Zip in a command line?

Use `-xr!directory1`:

```
7z a -t7z /home/backups/backup /home/files -xr!directory1
```

- `-r` tells 7-Zip **not** to recurse the directory.

Comment: Still not works, cant understand:
bash: !directory1/: event not found

Comment: You probably need to escape the `!` in bash. Try `-xr\!directory1`